# Query distinct emails across multiple tables?

Tags: postgresql

I got two tables with email addresses and a third table with a foreign key relation to the user table and I wish to get some distinct email addresses back. Here's a representation of the data:

Table 1 (user)

```
| Id       | Email          |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 1        | erik@test.com  |
| 2        | joe@test.com   |
| 3        | jack@mail.com  |
```

Table 2 - foreign key to user table

```
| Id       | user_id        |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 19       | 1              |
| 45       | 2              |
```

Table 3 (no relationship to the other two tables)

```
| Id       | email            |
| -------- | -----------------|
| 12       | erik@test.com   |
| 39       | steph@gmail.com |
```

How can I get all distinct email addresses from table 3 and table 1 where email does not exist in table 2 (fetched through user_id.email)

So in the scenario above, I'd like to get back:

```
jack@mail.com
steph@gmail.com
```

and exclude `erik@test.com` and `joe@test.com`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe what you want to do is a `union` between emails from Table 1 and Table 3, `except` emails of users from Table1 appearing in Table2:

```
(select "Email" from table1
union select "email" from table3)
except 
(select "Email" from Table1 inner join Table2
on Table1."Id" = Table2."user_id")
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=cb72ce8d8ef1a74b95e28da95b639e8a)